# PHP file upload not working although filetype is specified in the condition

Tags: php, file-upload

When I try to upload word doc(.docx) file it gives warning message "Sorry, only word, txt, rtf or pdf files are allowed. Sorry, your file was not uploaded." although in the if condition statement I have mentioned msword as one of the file types.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "./blog/wp-content/uploads/resumes";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadCV"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["uploadCV"]["size"] > 1024000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" && $imageFileType != "application/msword" && $imageFileType != "application/txt" && $imageFileType != "rtf;application/rtf" && $imageFileType != "application/pdf" && $imageFileType != "rtf;text/richtext" && $imageFileType != "rtf;text/richtext") {
    echo "Sorry, only word, txt, rtf or pdf files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadCV"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["uploadCV"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

HTML code

```
<form class="assessment-form-step-3" action="free-visa-assessment-form-process-3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <h2>About your Profession</h2>
                    <div>
                        <input class="assessment-occupation" name="assessment-occupation" data-validation="required" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min3" type="text" placeholder="Your occupation" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter your occupation">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <select class="assessment-highest-qualification" name="assessment-highest-qualification" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Please select your highest qualification">
                            <option value="">Select your highest level of qualification</option>
                            <option value="PhD">PhD</option>
                            <option value="Masters">Masters</option>
                            <option value="Bachelor">Bachelor</option>
                            <option value="Diploma">Diploma</option>
                            <option value="Certificate">Certificate</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <select class="assessment-experience" name="assessment-experience" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Please select appropriate type of visa that you're looking for">
                             <option value="">Select years of work experience</option>
                              <option value="Less than a year">Less than a year</option>
                              <option value="1 year">1 year</option>
                              <option value="2 years">2 years</option>
                              <option value="3 years">3 years</option>
                              <option value="4 years+">4 years+</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                       <label for="">Upload your resume (optional)</label>
                        <input type="file" class="uploadCV" name="uploadCV" id="uploadCV" accept=".doc,.docx,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/pdf,.pdf,text/plain,application/rtf">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <textarea name="assessment-comments" placeholder="Enter your comments" class="assessment-comments" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button class="full-width green proceed-to-thankyou">Submit &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <img style="width:22px;" src="img/lock-icon.png" alt=""></button>
                    <p></p>
                </form>
```

free-visa-assessment-form-process-3.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!$_POST['assessment-occupation'] || !$_POST['assessment-highest-qualification'] || !$_POST['assessment-experience']) {
    echo "<p>Please supply all of the data!</p>";
    exit;
}
else {
    require('db-connection.php');
    require('file-upload-script.php');
    try {  
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE visa SET job_title= :occupation, Qualifications= :qualification, experience= :experience, file_path= :file_upload, comments= :comments WHERE id= :id");

        // escape variables for security
        $stmt->bindParam(':occupation', $_POST['assessment-occupation']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':qualification', $_POST['assessment-highest-qualification']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':experience', $_POST['assessment-experience']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':file_upload', $target_file);
        $stmt->bindParam(':comments', $_POST['assessment-comments']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION["regId"]);

        $stmt->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes in your code

1)You are match file extension with MIME type

```
if($imageFileType != "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" && $imageFileType != "application/msword" && $imageFileType != "application/txt" && $imageFileType != "rtf;application/rtf" && $imageFileType != "application/pdf" && $imageFileType != "rtf;text/richtext" && $imageFileType != "rtf;text/richtext") {
```

2)You are passing target folder into `pathinfo()`

```
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

You have to create an array of extenction and match your array

```
 $allowed =  array('word', 'txt', 'rtf', 'pdf','docx');
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES["uploadCV"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);//pass file name here
    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
        echo "Sorry, only word, txt, rtf or pdf files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
```

Make sure you have added `enctype="multipart/form-data">` in your `form tag`

Comment: I'm still getting same warning message. Did I misconfigured html? `<input type="file" class="uploadCV" name="uploadCV" id="uploadCV">`

Comment: Have you add this `enctype="multipart/form-data">` to your form tag

Comment: I just now added but still getting same warning message.

Comment: post value of `print_r($_FILES);`!1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97051/discussion-between-rahul-shah-and-saty).

Comment: `$allowed = array('word', 'txt', 'rtf', 'pdf','docx'); `
add docx in this array

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` will return the extension of the file. So, if you want to allow txt, word, pdf, or rtf files, try this.

```
  //define an array containing file types
  $allowedFileTypes = array("txt", "pdf", "rtf", "docx", "doc");
  //condition to check
  if(!in_array($imageFileType, $allowedFileTypes ))
  {
      echo "Sorry, only word, txt, rtf or pdf files are allowed.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
  }
```

**edit**

You have to get the extension using this code.

```
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadCV']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: I'm still getting same warning message. Did I misconfigured html? `<input type="file" class="uploadCV" name="uploadCV" id="uploadCV">`

Comment: Still getting same warning message.